# Why Laravel gives wrong result query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
$groups = Groups::where("min", '>=', $result->Z)
    ->where("max", '<=', $result->Z)
    ->orderBy('min')
    ->get();
```

Where `$result->Z` is `52.850294770880225`.

So, I should get row:

```
4 | 47.01 | 52.99 | 0
```

[image]

Instead empty:

```
Collection {#631 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Comment: But 47.01 is not >= 52.85, nor is 52.99 <= 52.85... Why would you expect to get that row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your conditions the wrong way round. You're currently saying where `min` is bigger or equal to the value and `max` is smaller or equal to the value (which in theory should never happen).

Try:

```
$groups = Groups::where("min", '<=', $result->Z)
    ->where("max", '>=', $result->Z)
    ->orderBy('min')
    ->get();
```

Notice I've swapped the `>=` and `<=` around.